# Why array is displaying 'undefined' for the later values to be inserted in next indexes?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to **scrape** links of screenshots from  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en

I've used css class `T75of DYfLw`of `div<>` element to get the `src` all of screenshots. But instead of fetching links of all screenshots, below code displays desired output (links) for first values but displays undefined for next links (`src`) to be fetched.

```
 const appUrl = 'http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp';
 request(appUrl, function (error, response, html) {
    
   if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html); //cheerio


      
        let scLinks = [];
        $(".T75of.DYfLw ").each(function () {
            const link = $(this);
            const text = link.text();
            const href = link.attr('src');
            const app_full_url = href;
            scLinks.push(app_full_url);
        });
      console.log(scLinks);
     

    } 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div jsname="CmYpTb" class="JiLaSd u3EI9e">
  <div jsname="pCbVjb" class="SgoUSc" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -20, 0);">
    <button class="Q4vdJd" aria-label="Open screenshot 0" jscontroller="DeWHJf" jsaction="click:O1htCb" jsname="WR0adb" data-screenshot-item-index="0">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MMue08byixTw74ST_VkNQDUUJBgVEbjNHDYLhIuHmYhMIMJIp3KjVlnhhqZQOZUtNt8=w720-h310-rw" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MMue08byixTw74ST_VkNQDUUJBgVEbjNHDYLhIuHmYhMIMJIp3KjVlnhhqZQOZUtNt8=w1440-h620-rw 2x" class="T75of DYfLw" aria-hidden="true" alt="Screenshot Image" itemprop="image">
    </button>
    <button class="Q4vdJd" aria-label="Open screenshot 1" jscontroller="DeWHJf" jsaction="click:O1htCb" jsname="WR0adb" data-screenshot-item-index="1">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/foFmwvVGIwWWXJIukN7png18lFjFgbw3K7BqIm8G-jsFgSTVtkCa-dDkFApUzbvzIvbe=w720-h310-rw" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/foFmwvVGIwWWXJIukN7png18lFjFgbw3K7BqIm8G-jsFgSTVtkCa-dDkFApUzbvzIvbe=w1440-h620-rw 2x" class="T75of DYfLw" aria-hidden="true" alt="Screenshot Image" itemprop="image">
    </button>
    <button class="Q4vdJd" aria-label="Open screenshot 2" jscontroller="DeWHJf" jsaction="click:O1htCb" jsname="WR0adb" data-screenshot-item-index="2">
      <img data-ils="3" class="T75of DYfLw" aria-hidden="true" alt="Screenshot Image" itemprop="image" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iLgMXFO5qEPlTffpI21zaoG51AORnfu8NPb_2SdAXYgOYcb-xDOMfCryPhVvGNjoew=w1440-h620-rw 2x" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iLgMXFO5qEPlTffpI21zaoG51AORnfu8NPb_2SdAXYgOYcb-xDOMfCryPhVvGNjoew=w720-h310-rw">
    </button>
    <button class="Q4vdJd" aria-label="Open screenshot 3" jscontroller="DeWHJf" jsaction="click:O1htCb" jsname="WR0adb" data-screenshot-item-index="3">
      <img data-ils="3" class="T75of DYfLw" aria-hidden="true" alt="Screenshot Image" itemprop="image" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ElfUPGX67gv0TNQXuDxQGa5a4BYnLAZIgJJmoNoARvqlLQsKEQcNNWz-J_zqGV5vzQ=w1440-h620-rw 2x" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ElfUPGX67gv0TNQXuDxQGa5a4BYnLAZIgJJmoNoARvqlLQsKEQcNNWz-J_zqGV5vzQ=w720-h310-rw">
    </button>
    <button class="Q4vdJd" aria-label="Open screenshot 4" jscontroller="DeWHJf" jsaction="click:O1htCb" jsname="WR0adb" data-screenshot-item-index="4">
      <img data-ils="3" class="T75of DYfLw" aria-hidden="true" alt="Screenshot Image" itemprop="image" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wBgVA58O2xncQkksLatHGoNLI8L6o_1ZM8AC3GCScxCyaDOWOvMsMilaj1Scp3kEOIw=w1440-h620-rw 2x" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wBgVA58O2xncQkksLatHGoNLI8L6o_1ZM8AC3GCScxCyaDOWOvMsMilaj1Scp3kEOIw=w720-h310-rw">
    </button>
    <button class="Q4vdJd" aria-label="Open screenshot 5" jscontroller="DeWHJf" jsaction="click:O1htCb" jsname="WR0adb" data-screenshot-item-index="5">
      <img data-ils="3" class="T75of DYfLw" aria-hidden="true" alt="Screenshot Image" itemprop="image" srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nknhZ6--QSyZlohrv72BaPlwO2EHPvGKJY8NNACYY0IY8j4QKYATP6alT1yyMYb-35j9=w1440-h620-rw 2x" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nknhZ6--QSyZlohrv72BaPlwO2EHPvGKJY8NNACYY0IY8j4QKYATP6alT1yyMYb-35j9=w720-h310-rw">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: The code you've shown works fine by itself. This means that you may be executing it before the page has had all its content created (ie. if part of it is loaded asynchronously)

Comment: I 've updated my code. I am loading full html page using cheerio module. But I am unable to get you about how can is resolve this issue. I am beginner in node and programming.

Comment: In that case check the response in your `html` variable to see exactly what elements it contains.

Comment: The code you posted [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/zrcpb5jk/), which means your response html is wrong - look at previous comment.

Comment: can you explain me how can I check response for html variable?

Comment: first two `<img>` tags have an attribute `src` which contains url and are found in that loop, the rest `<img>` tags have `srcset` which contains url and  there no `src` attribute in these tags; hence undefined.

Comment: thank you @ARr0w. yes there was problem in css of webpage. first two `<img>`  tags  have `src` and other `<img>` tags have `data-src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets define a recursive function which gets the data from the existing attribute of all the possible attributes one of which will exist.

```
function getValueofAttr(elem,attrArray,startIndex){
   var data = elem.attr(attrArray[startIndex]);
   if(href  === undefined || href  === ''){
     if( attrArray.length > startIndex){
        data = getValueofAttr(elem,attrArray,index+1);
     }
   }
   return data;
}
```

test run example :

```
 var link = $('.SomeSpecificControl'); //class of some html tag.
 var href = getValueofAttr(link,['src','data-src','href'],0);
```

now for your scenario :

```
$(".T75of.DYfLw ").each(function () {
    const link = $(this);
    const text = link.text();
    const href = getValueofAttr(link,['src','data-src','srcset'],0);
    const app_full_url = href;
    scLinks.push(app_full_url);
});
```